# How can I add a string to ticketIds field?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access ticketIds field on Firebase Firestore and update this List. Every time when the method works it should add a random String value to this list. How can I do it?

My firestore.[image]

I have written such a method for checking some conditions.I want to know how can I effectively access this value?

```
Future<void> buyTickets(
    {required String userId,
    required List<Map<String, dynamic>> tickets}) async {
  try {
    DocumentSnapshot doc =
        await firestore.collection('tickets').doc(userId).get();
    if (doc.data() == null) {
      firestore
          .collection('tickets')
          .doc(userId)
          .set({"ticketList": tickets});
    } else {
      // User had purchased smt before
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
          await firestore.collection('tickets').doc(userId).get();
      var ticketList = (snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['ticketList']
          as List<dynamic>;
      for (Map<String, dynamic> e in tickets) {
        if (ticketList.any((element) => element['prize'] == e['prize'])) {
          //Update current ticket

          int index = ticketList
              .indexWhere((element) => element['prize'] == e['prize']);

          String uid = nanoid(length: 6);
          DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
              await firestore.collection('tickets').doc(userId).get();
          ticketList =
              (snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['ticketList'];
          var newGeneratedTicketIDS = ticketList[index]['ticketIds'].add(uid);
          print(newGeneratedTicketIDS);
              
          // firestore
          //     .collection('tickets')
          //     .doc(userId)
          //     .update({"ticketList": []});

          print('buraya');
        } else {
          //add a ticket that does not exist
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (error, s) {
    print(error.toString());
    print(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that your `e` variable contains the current ticket from `ticketList`, you can add an item to its `tickerIds` array with:

```
final ticketIds = e['ticketIds'] as List;
ticketIds.add(uid);
```

Comment: Thank you much Sir...however it does not update ticketIds list